# Get all fieldnames from a table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am coding on Vb.net and using ms-Access on recordset. I want to get all the fieldnames from a table.

is it something like this?

```
somestring = rs.Fields(Name).Value
```

UPDATE:It did not work...I do not need the value, What I want is the field name.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ComputerVersteher What does it "{0,-20}{1}" mean on that code?

Comment: @Sam1996: sorry i'm from Ms Access VBA fraction, not VB.Net, but the docs to [Console.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) may help.

Comment: Why ADO and not ADO.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the name of the `i`'th field. `rs.Fields.Count` is the number of fields in `Fields`. Each field has also many other properties. See [Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/field-object?view=sql-server-2017).

```
rs.Fields(i).Name
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess i explained wrong, I want to get the fieldname from all rows, not the values in each record, only the name, For example: `ID; Name; Last Name; City; SSN ` does stuffs, Thank you a lot

Comment: I see I have a getrows, but i do not know if i have to use this

Comment: @Sam1996 - Yes this is not clear. Fields are the columns of your table. They have names like you said, `ID`, etc. Is that not what you want to get?

Comment: @RobertBaron: `rs`can result on a query too. Valid approach is the marked dupe by HereGoes, what enables you to iterate through all tables too.

Comment: @RobertBaron Sorry, I do not want to get the values. What I want is just like the  name of each row, `ID; Name; Last Name; City; SSN` etc, I do not want, for example: `1; Sam; Banave; Los Angeles; 32442342` . Sorry, I am not very clear in english.

Comment: @Sam1996 - I understand. I think your are mixing rows and columns (fields). Rows have no name, they just contain the values, one value per column (field). If you already have a `Recordset` then the `Fields` collection contain the names you are looking for. If you do have a `RecordSet`, then look at the duplicate question. Your question is all but clearly stated. An example, of what your problem is would have helped.

Comment: @RobertBaron ooh okay...Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Sam1996 - No problem, try it out!

Comment: @RobertBaron Last question, I saw that in recordset does not have getschema. Am I right?

Comment: @Sam1996 - You are right, it does not. See [Recordset Object Properties, Methods, and Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-properties-methods-and-events?view=sql-server-2017).